# Import Excel with strings and numbers in exponential writing

Tags: r, excel, load, xlsx

I have a database in Excel that looks like this:

```
Name    Note    Value1    Value2
Adidas  first   1.74E-06  1.06E-07
```

and so on, there are thousands of rows and a bunch of columns with values.

However, when I use:

```
data<-read.xlsx2("data.xlsx",header = T,sheetIndex = 1,colClasses="numeric")
```

it returns everything as strings:

`is.numeric(data$X1)`

`[1] FALSE`

So far I worked around it like this:`as.numeric(as.character(data$X1))` - but with many columns it becomes very tiring.

How can I upload it directly right without using this kind of tricks?

Comment: Can you try `library(readxl);
read_excel('yourfile.xlsx')#
    Name  Note   Value1   Value2
   (chr) (chr)    (dbl)    (dbl)
1 Adidas first 1.74e-06 1.06e-07`  It worked by copy/pasting the example.

Comment: That worked. I'm surprised it worked with `read_excel` but it didn't with `xlsx2`. Thanks

Comment: @llja I haven't tried with `xlsx2`..  One possibility is that you specified the `colClasses='numeric` instead of `colClasses=c('character', 'character', 'numeric', 'numeric')`.  I am guessing that it recycles the 'numeric' to each column and as the first column is obviously not 'numeric', the whole columns get the class of the first column .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `read_excel`

```
 library(readx)
 read_excel('file1.xlsx')
 #   Source: local data frame [1 x 4]

 #    Name  Note   Value1   Value2
 #   (chr) (chr)    (dbl)    (dbl)
 #1 Adidas first 1.74e-06 1.06e-07
```

---

As I mentioned in the comments, if we are using the `colClasses`, then we need to specify it for the whole columns

```
library(xlsx)
str(read.xlsx2('file1.xlsx', sheetIndex=1, colClasses=c('character', 
         'character', 'numeric', 'numeric'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
#   'data.frame':   1 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ Name  : chr "Adidas"
#  $ Note  : chr "first"
#  $ Value1: num 1.74e-06
#  $ Value2: num 1.06e-07
```